# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre innerHTML y outerHTML?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber la diferencia entre `innerHTML`, `outerHTML` como así también `innerText` y `outerText` dentro de `javascript`

Comment: Hola Pachi. ¿Has mirado la documentacion de las propiedades que indicas para entenderlas mejor? ¿Que problemas tuviste tras leerlo?  Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 9):

*Diferencia entre innerHTML y outerHTML*

`innerHTML` devuelve el texto contenido en las etiquetas html.

`outerHTML` devuelve el texto contenido en las etiquetas html y las propias etiquetas.

**Ejemplo**

```html
<body>
  
<span id="span">soy un span</span>   

<script>
    var valor = document.getElementById("span");
    alert(valor.innerHTML); //Muestra "soy un span"
    alert(valor.outerHTML); //Muestra "<span id="span">soy un span</span>"
</script>
</body>
```

*Diferencia entre innerText y outerText*

`innerText` devuelve el texto que se encuentra en las etiquetas html.

`outerText` devuelve el texto contenido en las etiquetas incluidas las etiquetas.

¿Cúal es por tanto la diferencia entre innerHTML y innerText?

`innerText` es interpretado como texto plano mientras que `innerHTML` es interpretado en formato html, para que te quede claro te pondré este ejemplo:

**Ejemplo**

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Process(val){
    var obj = document.getElementById("div_1");
     if(val==1){
         obj.innerText = "<h4 style='color:blue;'>Algún Texto</h4>";
     }else{
         obj.innerHTML = "<h4 style='color:blue;'>Algún Texto</h4>";
     }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div id="div_1">
    </div>
    <form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="">
        <input type="text" name="t1"/>
       <input type="button" value="innerText" onclick="Process(1)"/>
        <input type="button" value="innerHTML" onclick="Process(2)"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Cuando dices ***mientras que `innerHTML` es interpretado en formato html***, esto no es así, el `innerHTML` es también un texto plano, lo que pasa es que al agregarlo dentro del `div` pasa a ser en formato _HTML_.

Answer (score 1):

Pongamos el código HTML siguiente:

```
<div id="uno"><strong>Esto</strong> es un <a href="/">Ejemplo</a></div>
```

- **innerHTML** del elemento `#id` nos devolvería el html *interior* de la etiqueta:

  ```
  <strong>Esto</strong> es un <a href="/">Ejemplo</a>
  ```
- **outerHTML** del mismo nos devolvería el HTML completo del elemento:

  ```
  <div id="uno"><strong>Esto</strong> es un <a href="/">Ejemplo</a></div>
  ```
- **innerText** nos devolvería el /texto/ interior del elemento:

  ```
  Esto es un ejemplo
  ```
- **outerText** no es un atributo estándar, pero habitualmente nos devolvería el texto interior (como innerText). La diferencia es que, si se le asigna algo, reemplazará todo el elemento en vez de sólo su contenido.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.